# Typerror when using Geopandas.to_file

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, shapely, typeerror

I am trying to save some Shapely Polygons to a .shp so that I can view and map them in QGIS. This data resides in my projects.hull column. I am running into a Typeerror which I am finding difficult to understand. It looks like the error occurs when a geopandas function fails to evaluate type(np.zeros(1)) but when I run `type(np.zeros(1))` myself, that is working well and evaluates to `np.ndarray`. I also tried reducing the array just one column (one that I wanted to save) but that did not fix the issue and the error persisted.

I somehow feel that the error lies with my data rather than my code.

According to [this link](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2017/lessons/L2/geopandas-basics.html#writing-a-shapefile), saving the Shapely polygons can be done like this:

```py
# Determine the output path for the Shapefile
outfp = r"/home/geo/Data/Senaatintori.shp"

# Write the data into that Shapefile
newdata.to_file(out)
```

My Data just before saving

```
+-------+----------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| index |  project_uid   | Max_Download_No_Nulls  |                      points                        |                     geometry                       |                       hull                         |                 centroid                  | area_km^2   | premises  | density  |
+-------+----------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|    0  | Stirling_0_-1  | 5.496183               | MULTIPOINT (-4.19633 56.21460, -4.29470 56.111...  | MULTIPOINT (-467133.297 7601256.060, -478083.7...  | POLYGON ((-466658.619 7560907.084, -474715.156...  | (7587009.99623611, -468692.8416761144)    | 678.822059  |      131  | 0.192981 |
|    1  | Stirling_0_0   | 9.185185               | MULTIPOINT (-4.22831 56.24559, -4.24566 56.248...  | MULTIPOINT (-470693.138 7607461.293, -472624.3...  | POLYGON ((-472990.360 7605506.979, -473953.975...  | (7607333.977542202, -472053.11493638257)  | 7.847124    |       27  | 3.440751 |
|    2  | Stirling_0_1   | 13.903226              | MULTIPOINT (-4.19504 56.05044, -4.19374 56.048...  | MULTIPOINT (-466989.338 7568463.333, -466845.0...  | POLYGON ((-466112.018 7567006.315, -467841.667...  | (7568425.799942268, -467883.79938050144)  | 3.664275    |       31  | 8.460065 |
|    3  | Stirling_0_2   | 8.859649               | MULTIPOINT (-4.24484 56.06827, -4.24473 56.069...  | MULTIPOINT (-472533.817 7572018.742, -472520.9...  | POLYGON ((-471700.190 7569746.740, -473787.007...  | (7571923.565722667, -472337.5122653291)   | 11.834822   |       57  | 4.816296 |
|    4  | Stirling_0_3   | 7.294118               | MULTIPOINT (-4.17482 56.11993, -4.17445 56.123...  | MULTIPOINT (-464738.302 7582328.305, -464698.0...  | POLYGON ((-465544.010 7579884.066, -468237.552...  | (7584176.272135137, -463871.6328713002)   | 44.743719   |       68  | 1.519766 |
+-------+----------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

My projects.info() output:

```
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
Int64Index: 59 entries, 0 to 58
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------                 --------------  -----   
 0   project_uid            59 non-null     object  
 1   Max_Download_No_Nulls  59 non-null     float64 
 2   points                 59 non-null     geometry
 3   geometry               59 non-null     geometry
 4   hull                   59 non-null     geometry
 5   centroid               59 non-null     object  
 6   area_km^2              59 non-null     float64 
 7   premises               59 non-null     int64   
 8   density                59 non-null     float64 
dtypes: float64(3), geometry(3), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 4.6+ KB
```

My code:

```py
#converting to a crm that uses meters
projects = projects.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})


#getting ready to find density
projects['hull'] = projects.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.convex_hull)
projects['centroid'] = projects.hull.apply(lambda x: (x.centroid.y, x.centroid.x))
projects['area_km^2'] = projects.hull.apply(lambda x: (x.area))/(1000*1000)
projects['premises'] = projects.points.apply(len)
projects['density'] = projects.premises / projects["area_km^2"] #unknown units


#ofcom mean speed
projects['Max_Download_No_Nulls'] = projects.Max_Download_No_Nulls.apply(np.mean)

prjs_save_path = "outputs/prjs/projects.shp"
projects.to_file(prjs_save_path)
projects.head()
```

Error Message:

```py
/home/wojtek/anaconda3/envs/broadway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyproj/crs/crs.py:53: FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated. '<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method. When making the change, be mindful of axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6
  return _prepare_from_string(" ".join(pjargs))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-cf5ef1956086> in <module>
     30 #projects['cabinets_in_hull'] = projects.apply(lambda x: get_points_within(cabinets, x.hull), axis=1)
     31 
---> 32 projects.to_file(prjs_save_path)
     33 projects.head()

~/anaconda3/envs/broadway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)
    531         from geopandas.io.file import to_file
    532 
--> 533         to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)
    534 
    535     def to_crs(self, crs=None, epsg=None, inplace=False):

~/anaconda3/envs/broadway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in to_file(df, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)
    177         df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
    178     if schema is None:
--> 179         schema = infer_schema(df)
    180     with fiona_env():
    181         crs_wkt = None

~/anaconda3/envs/broadway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in infer_schema(df)
    221 
    222     properties = OrderedDict(
--> 223         [
    224             (col, convert_type(col, _type))
    225             for col, _type in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes)

~/anaconda3/envs/broadway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    222     properties = OrderedDict(
    223         [
--> 224             (col, convert_type(col, _type))
    225             for col, _type in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes)
    226             if col != df._geometry_column_name

~/anaconda3/envs/broadway/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in convert_type(column, in_type)
    209             out_type = types[str(in_type)]
    210         else:
--> 211             out_type = type(np.zeros(1, in_type).item()).__name__
    212         if out_type == "long":
    213             out_type = "int"

TypeError: data type not understood
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found that keeping multiple Shapely columns in the GDF broke it so I fixed by creating a GDF with just one Shapely column.

```py
hulls = gpd.GeoDataFrame(projects[["project_uid","area_km^2","premises","density"]], crs = projects.crs, geometry=projects.hull)
hulls.to_file(prjs_save_path)
hulls.head()
```